# Do the commentators describe how Amram and Yocheved felt through the events involving Paro's daughter and Moshe?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos

The intervention of Paro's daughter in the life of Moshe was clearly miraculous. Basya went against her father's wishes and Moshe's mother was paid to nurse him. One can imagine the feelings of wonder that Amram and Yocheved must have had.

But then Chap 2 v 10
“When the child grew up, she brought him to Pharaoh’s daughter, who made him her son.” and as a result, he spent his time in Paro's palace (see [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2.10?lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Bahya&lang2=en)).  One can imagine that  Amram and Yocheved must have had worries about that.

So my question is do the meforshim or midroshim describe the feelings of  Amram and Yocheved through these events?

Comment: why do we need midroshim to describe how they felt? is there any doubt that they felt bad about it? But _Bas Paro_ had an affinity for him, so what could they do?

Comment: see my answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119325/did-the-jews-know-that-moshe-was-the-future-redeemer-and-being-raised-in-the-pal/119333#119333